# User Hierarchy Wordpress - Manager can see only some users

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a plugin that help me with this:

For example, you have a user with a role “Manager” and I want that user can see just some users.

This is because I want to have some Managers and they can see just the users assigned to them.

Thank you.

**[Edit]**

[image]

User 2 and User 6 are managers, they have people assigned to them, the request is that manager (User 2) can't see the users assigned to another manager (User 6).

Answer (score 1):

Try this Member Plugin hope this helpful

https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/